# How to get form data values in laravel controller

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I am using laravel with angular js, I want to post the form with image, audio and video, This is my ajax,

```
 $scope.update_defects = function(){

    var file_data = $('#fileaudio').prop('files')[0];
    var file_data1 = $('#filevideo').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();

    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    form_data.append('file1', file_data1);
    form_data.append('snag_id', $scope.projectSnagId);
    form_data.append('defect_id', $scope.defect_number);
    form_data.append('defect_type', $scope.defect_type);
    form_data.append('defect_desc', $scope.defect_desc);

    $http({
        url:"{{url('update_si_defects')}}",
        method:"POST",
        data:form_data,
    }).success(function(data, status, config, header) {
    }).error(function(data, status, config, header) {
        alert("Defect data retrieval error");
    });
    }
```

This is my laravel controller,

```
 public function update_si_defects(Request $request)
    {

    echo $request->defect_type;
    exit();       
    }
```

But I am unable to get the submitted values in controller, what is the correct way? please suggest any solution?

Comment: Tried `$request->input('file')` ?

Comment: for other text filelds?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: `$request->all();` will allow you to retrieve all the inputs

Comment: Its not returning values, is anything wrong with my ajax?

Comment: Yes, your ajax doesn't have csrf token! I think that is what is wrong